# How to import a library with its local files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, filepath, sys

I am trying to import a library that I've created to another Python script. When I import it, it can't read files locally, meaning, its filepath is off.

I use Python3.6.6
Ubuntu 16.04

1st approach

```
import sys
sys.path.append ("/home/myName/Desktop/myLibrary")

# myScript is in myLibrary
# it reads some files when being imported
import myScript
```

2nd approach

```
import importlib.util

spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location ("myLibrary", 
     "/home/myName/Desktop/myLibrary/myScript.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec (spec)
spec.loader.exec_module (foo)
```

The error that I get in both instances:
`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'data/myFile.csv' does not exist: b'data/myFile.csv'`

Data directory is in myLibrary.

When I run `os.getcwd()` in myScript, I get:

`/home/myName/Desktop/myLibrary`

When I import myScript and then `os.getcwd()` is being run, I get:

`/home/myName/Desktop/otherLibrary`

Any idea why working directory is off and how should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

os.getcwd() does a bit more than returning the current working directory. It defaults to $PWD in your env. It's not where the script is located but where you were when you executed the script.

You can solve it via relative path. `__file__` provides path of the file which runs. `os.path.dirname` provide the directory of given file. It means you can get the folder of you running Python file. So you can provide the path based on the folder of you Python file.

**Eg.:**

`sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), "your_relative_path", "your_python_file.py"))`

if the path of your running Python file is `/home/user/python_script/test.py`, then `/home/user/python_script/your_relative_path/your_python_file.py` path will be appended to your path.

**FYI:**

If you use this line before `import` then you will give a warning: (Module level import not at top of file (E402)) BUT you can suppress this warning whit this comment line: `...  # noqa: E402`

Answer (score 0):

The special variable `__file__` allways contains the full path of the script itself. This is also true for a imported module.

You can use this to find some local data file. This does however require changing the **module** file to load the data in a different way.  Here's a basic example to demonstrate it (I assumed Linux):

I created a library directory `myLibrary` in `/var/tmp` and a sub-directory `data` for the local file to read:

```
mkdir -p /var/tmp/myLibrary/data
```

Then, as test data, I created a text file:

```
echo 'Hello from test file'  > /var/tmp/myLibrary/data/testfile.txt
```

The module `/var/tmp/myLibrary/myScript.py` looks like this:

```
import os.path

# Prepare path to data file realative to this module.
#
libdir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
data_file_path = os.path.join(libdir, 'data/testfile.txt')

# Open the file
#
my_data_file = open(data_file_path)

# Read and show the data from the file
#
data = my_data_file.read()
print(data)
```

And a simple script to import this module. When run, it will print the contents of the data file just by importing the library module:

```
import sys
sys.path.append ('/var/tmp/myLibrary')
import myScript
```